# Typescript arrow function object with new key won't give any errors

Tags: reactjs, constants, new-operator, arrow-functions, react-functional-component

In my typescript code I'm not getting any errors when I use the new keyword to create an Arrow function object. now i know according to the documentation, You can not use new keyword to create an Object from Arrow function. But  why am I now gettting any errors?[image: My code in the VS code]

I was expecting an Error according to the dicumentation. but this is working perfectly.

Comment: Please post your code as plain text with code format instead of screenshots

Comment: I just wanted to show everyone, that there are no compile errors. how am I going to do it by posting in a Text format?